# Finding relationship between java classes

Tags: java

I would like to create a graph which contains Java classes of a program as nodes and the relationships between the classes as edges. How can I determine the relationships between classes? I thought about checking the import statements, but they are often inaccurate because of the * wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a compiler.

Or look at compiled code.

Easiest kludgey way: Load the code and apply `java.lang.reflect` (or a library which uses that).

The difficult way: Read the class files. Probably use one of the libraries which handles this.